# qgis2web - layers are not shown

Tags: qgis2web

I want to export my project with qgis2web. In the Export-Dialogue, the layers that should be visible are activated, but not shown in the preview screen, just the zoom-in and zoom-out sign. Also after exporting the map is shown, but has no content. Any hints?